# Rollup dynamic module resolution

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, rollupjs

I'm trying to use [Rollup](http://rollupjs.org) to bundle some JS into a single file. However the path of one of the files I'd like to `import` is only known at compile time, and so I need to tell Rollup how to find it.

Here's my main file:

```js
import * as commands from 'command-loader';

console.log(commands);
```

You can see it's importing everything from `command-loader`. The name and the contents of the file are not important, I just need its contents bundled into the main file. That file looks something like:

```js
export function exampleCommand() {
  console.log('Running command...');
}
```

The Rollup error is pretty clear that it doesn't know how to find `command-loader`: `'command-loader' is imported by ../index.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency`.

I know that I could probably just read the contents of the commands file and prepend it to the main file, but that feels awkward as I'd have to remove the `export` from the commands file and define a "commands" object, and this probably defeats the purpose of Rollup.

I've tried using [`rollup-plugin-node-resolve`](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-node-resolve) to tell Rollup how to find `command-loader`, but it did not seem to work (granted, I don't know the plugin that well).

```js
const rollup = require('rollup');
const resolve = require('rollup-plugin-node-resolve');

await rollup.rollup({
  input: mainFilePath,
  plugins: [
    resolve({
      'command-loader': dynamicFilePath
    })
  ]
});
```

I've also tried using [`rollup-plugin-bundle-imports`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-bundle-imports) to no avail.

```js
const rollup = require('rollup');
const { bundleImports } = require('rollup-plugin-bundle-imports');

await rollup.rollup({
  input: mainFilePath,
  plugins: [
    bundleImports({
      include: [dynamicFilePath],
      importAs: 'command-loader',
    })
  ]
});
```

Maybe I'm taking the wrong approach. If there is a better way to dynamically `import` a file at compile time I'd love to learn about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it: [`@rollup/plugin-alias`](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/alias)

> A Rollup plugin for defining aliases when bundling packages.

Here's the code I ended up using:

```js
const rollup = require('rollup');
const alias = require('@rollup/plugin-alias');

await rollup.rollup({
  input: mainFilePath,
  plugins: [
    alias({
      entries: {
        'command-loader': dynamicFilePath
      }
    })
  ]
});
```

That, combined with CJS output format, parses the above example code and yields:

```js
'use strict';

function exampleCommand() {
  console.log('Running command...');
}

var commands = /*#__PURE__*/Object.freeze({
  __proto__: null,
  exampleCommand: exampleCommand
});

console.log(commands);
```

Success!